# Getting error when installing php in Centos 7.4 OPENSSL_1.0.2

Tags: linux, centos, php, apache-2.4, openssl

I am trying for a couple of days to install php without any luck. The process which usually takes 2 minutes. I have CentOS 7.4.1708 and Apache 2.4.6. 
 When I install php using `yum install php` and run the command 
`php -v` I get the error `php: /lib64/libcrypto.so.10: version OPENSSL_1.0.2 not found (required by php)` 
When I run command `rpm -qi openssl` 
I get `package openssl is not installed` 
 When I run `openssl version` 
 I get `OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013` 
When I run command `yum info openssl` 
I get

`Available Packages
Name        : openssl
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 1.0.2k
Release     : 8.el7
Size        : 492 k
Repo        : base/7/x86_64
Summary     : Utilities from the general purpose cryptography library with TLS implementation
URL         : http://www.openssl.org/
License     : OpenSSL
Description : The OpenSSL toolkit provides support for secure communications between
            : machines. OpenSSL includes a certificate management tool and shared
            : libraries which provide various cryptographic algorithms and
            : protocols.`

yum info php gives 
`Available Packages
Name        : php
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 5.4.16
Release     : 43.el7_4.1
Size        : 1.4 M
Repo        : updates/7/x86_64
Summary     : PHP scripting language for creating dynamic web sites
URL         : http://www.php.net/
License     : PHP and Zend and BSD
Description : PHP is an HTML-embedded scripting language. PHP attempts to make it
            : easy for developers to write dynamically generated web pages. PHP also
            : offers built-in database integration for several commercial and
            : non-commercial database management systems, so writing a
            : database-enabled webpage with PHP is fairly simple. The most common
            : use of PHP coding is probably as a replacement for CGI scripts.
            : 
            : The php package contains the module (often referred to as mod_php)
            : which adds support for the PHP language to Apache HTTP Server.`

The output of `yum update openssl` is

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
base                                                                                        | 3.6 kB  00:00:00     
cm-rhel7-8.0                                                                                | 1.3 kB  00:00:00     
cm-rhel7-8.0-updates                                                                        | 1.3 kB  00:00:00     
epel/x86_64/metalink                                                                        |  29 kB  00:00:00     
extras                                                                                      | 3.4 kB  00:00:00     
updates                                                                                     | 3.4 kB  00:00:00     
webtatic                                                                                    | 3.6 kB  00:00:00     
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirroring.pulsant.co.uk
 * cm-rhel7-8.0: updates-eu.brightcomputing.com
 * cm-rhel7-8.0-updates: updates-eu.brightcomputing.com
 * epel: www.mirrorservice.org
 * extras: centos.mirroring.pulsant.co.uk
 * updates: centos.mirroring.pulsant.co.uk
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
101 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
No packages marked for update
```

Here is the output of command ldd `/lib64/libcrypto.so.10`

`linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00002aaaaaaab000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00002aaaaaea8000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00002aaaab0ac000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002aaaab2c3000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000555555554000)`

Output of command `openssl version -a`

`` openssl: /lib64/libcrypto.so.10: version `OPENSSL_1.0.2' not found (required by openssl) ``

Here is the output of `which openssl`

`/usr/bin/openssl`

Output of `env | grep LD_` is empty.

Okay I am getting forward, with this command `yum reinstall openssl openssl-libs`
That error is gone. Now there is small issue I think. The output of `php -v` is 

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so' - libzip.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Mar  7 2018 13:34:47) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies`

How to get the correct version of php and openssl to get rid of the error?

Comment: Remove all the third party repositories from the system, and then run `yum distro-sync`.

Comment: Hi Michael, removed all repos except the default ones. removed php and reinstalled it after removing the extra repos. Ran the above command but the error is still there.

Comment: what's the output of ```ldd /lib64/libcrypto.so.10```?

Comment: also run ```openssl version -a```. Which version of openssl do you have?

Comment: The output of both commands added to the question end.

Comment: Post the output from `which openssl` and `env | grep LD_`.  It looks like you have multiple versions installed, along with an inconsistent environment that picks up portions of both.

Comment: Do you have any version locks set on those packages? Try with `yum versionlock list` if openssl is listed do `yum versionlock clear` and `yum reinstall openssl openssl-libs`

Comment: `yum reinstall libzip` got rid of the remaining issue too.

Comment: Many thanks. Could you please organise your work as answer. Thanks.

Comment: fyi, `mod_php` is not recommended way to use php with apache

Answer (score 1):

To make it work on Centos 7

`yum install -y php php-common`

`yum reinstall -y openssl openssl-libs`

`systemctl restart httpd`

Answer (score 0):

To fix your issues, these command should help:

```
yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm -y
yum reinstall openssl openssl-libs -y
yum reinstall libzip -y

yum install https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php54
yum install php php-common php-pecl-zip -y
```

But clients with openssl version less than 1.1.0 will not allow letsencrypt certificates since yesterday.
best practice for centos 7 it's install latest version of openssl from source because it is not exist at any yum repositories as package
you can make it with this this script:

```
yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm -y
yum groupinstall -y "Development Tools" "Development Libraries"

cd /usr/src
wget --no-check-certificate https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1l.tar.gz
tar -zxf openssl-1.1.1l.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.1.1l
./config
make
make install
mv /usr/local/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1 /usr/local/lib64/libssl.so.1.1 /usr/lib64/
yum install php php-common -y
yum install ca-certificates -y 
systemctl restart httpd
```

Also i would recommend you install at least 7+version of php instead very deprecated 5.4
You can do that so:

```
yum install https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm -y
yum-config-manager --disable 'remi-php*'
yum-config-manager --enable   remi-php74
yum install php php-common -y # and others packages you need
```

Comment: Let's Encrypt certificate chains with OpenSSL 1.0.2 as shipped by RHEL/CentOS 7 work properly after updating to ca-certificates-2021.2.50-72.el7_9.